# pip3 wasnt recognized as name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file or an executeable program

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

im getting headaches but im still trying to find the error
vs code says it couldnt exec pip3 install selenium

ive got py 3.11 installed, shouldnt pip be installed by default?
im trying to get selenium and webdriver going to make a bot for messaging

but im constantly failing cuz of the webdriver issue i got - mainly because of the pip error
i tried to reinstall python, webdriver, even considered downloading selenium and pip manually

```
+ pip3 install selenium
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You have python3 installed -- which OS are you using?

Comment: im using windows 10

Comment: There you -- one of the first results of a search: https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-use-a-python-3-virtual-environment-in-windows-10/ Create a virtual environment, activate it, and add whatever packages you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it working for now. Im off to scripting! Thanks again mate :)